# Ubuntu Desktop 20 and 22 DNS defect with manual IP configuration

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 20 / 22 desktop from an ISO into VMware Player. During installation time the VM has internet access, with an ethernet interface using NAT.  It gets a valid IP configuration through DHCP.

So, I installed one more package, then set the interface to `local network only` in VMware player. Went to the Ubuntu GUI configuration for the network interface. I disabled DHCP, configured a valid IP address, netmask, default gateway and a DNS server I run in that virtual network.

Then I configured HAproxy to reverse proxy an IIS I have... and it works. With HTTP. All configured with IP addresses.

And then my trouble begins. For using SSL I need name resolution. DNS name resolution of target servers e.g., found the HAproxy can't find the target system.

Then opened a terminal, tried a ping to a server which has certainly a name resolution in my DNS server (on Windows this works perfectly) but it keeps saying:

```
ping: 16dc: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

As this happens with Ubuntu 20 desktop and 22 desktop out of the box and I already spent half a day... I assume that the GUI for network settings is unable to apply a manual IP configuration.

Running `nmcli` I get:

```
NS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.3.198
        interface: ens33
```

That's my DNS resolver. I can ping it.

Regardless what I try (`resolv.conf`, the `netplan` yaml file) the box seems not to send the DNS request.
Netplan try tells me that even the YAML file is correct.
This one contains also the correct DNS server
`/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` . Reboot does not help

I am at end of my knowledge... and seeing the countless other posts and their solutions (not working on my system) I just wanna know how to fix that.

Edit: I have a lot of Linux experience, mostly with Redhat distributions and Suse,  and with older releases of Ubuntu. I never had any problems.

Comment: In Ubuntu, the default DNS resolver is `resolved`.  What does `resolvectl status` show for the configured DNS servers?